# Why v-for item not reactive and not changed?

Tags: vue.js

Why name 2 not changed and not reactive? What wrong?
How can I make it reactive so that when the properties of the object change, the DOM also changes?
When I delete Name 2 nothing happens

```
<template>

  <div>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in items" v-bind:key="item.id">
      <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    </div>    
    <button v-on:click="deleteItem">
      Delete Name 2
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data:function(){
    return {
      items:[
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Name 1"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Name 2"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    deleteItem: function(){
        this.items[1] = [];
        console.log(this.items);
        alert("DELETED");
      }
  },
  created: function(){
    let self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
      self.items[1] = [];
    }, 2000);
  }
};
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reactivity in vue (2) is a little bit tricky, this link explain you how to solve this issue
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays

Answer (score 2):

You are actually assigning an empty array to item with index 1, instead of removing it.
If you want to remove the element with index 1 simply use [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and Vue will automatically react to it:

```
this.items.splice(1, 1); // The first 1 is the index
```

Or, alternatively use Vue.delete(), which is originally to remove properties from object, but can also remove items from arrays:

```
Vue.delete(this.items, 1); // 1 is the index
```

More info: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-delete

Answer (score 1):

Modify your delete item function. Don't set it to an empty array. Filter the array like this:

Your HTML Markup :

```
<button @click="deleteItem(2)">
  Delete Name 2
</button>
```

Send the id of the item that you want to delete to the **deleteItem()** as an argument.

```
 deleteItem: function(itemId){
    let filtered = this.items.filter((each) => {
      return each.id !== itemId;
    })
    this.items = filtered; //Finally mutate the items[] in data
  }
```